# CSS border within a border?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to do a CSS border within a border?

Here is what I'm trying to do: [screenshot](http://min.us/lbcAznjCdoJOMu)

[image]

I would like to avoid extra html elements and also avoid using images because of retina devices. If only I could put a CSS outline on only one side of the element I would be golden, but this doesn't seem to be possible.

Edit:

Here's what I've ended up with from the many excellent solutions that were posted - thank you!

http://jsfiddle.net/kisabelle/9umMr/1/

HTML

```
<footer>
 <p>Example</p>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer{
 border-top: 15px solid #393734;
 position: relative;
}

footer:after{
 content:"";
 border-top: 2px #989593 dotted;
 position:absolute;
 top: -8px; 
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:0;
}
```

Using the pseudo-element :after to add a second border (instead of box-shadow) allows support in IE8 and up.

See the jsfiddle for a second example in which you can control the space between the dots in the dotted border using the CSS `content` attribute instead of a border.

Comment: Link to drop box fails.

Comment: the dropbox link is broken

Comment: Your link to screenshot does not display. Perhaps try using an image sharing site like minus.com or some such.

Comment: I would also suggest maybe some code examples of what you have tried so far. Could link to jsFiddle for that.

Comment: Your dropbox link doesn't work.

Comment: Check [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/)

Comment: Want something like this? It's using the `:after` pseudo element.. **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/S4YQb/)**

Comment: thanks for the heads up the link works for me so I didn't realize it wouldn't work for everyone else. updated the link.

Comment: I see the image yet I don't understand what you want to do. I would suggest wrapping it with another DIV and controlling the border of that as you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of options:

1. Use border + outline
2. Use pseudo elements
3. Use multiple box-shadows
4. Use border-image

Googling any of those brings up loads of resources

Now that I've seen the screen grab, I reckon a combination of border top plus some box-shadows is your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/ne9nm/

Edit: Update the JSFiddle to show two possible solutions; one using box-shadows, and one using a pseudo element.

The HTML:

```
<div id="example-1">Example 1</div>
<div id="example-2">Example 2</div>
```

The CSS:

```
  div {
      background:rgb(100, 150, 100);
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      padding:30px;
      margin:20px;
  }
  #example-1 {
      border-top:1px white dotted;
      box-shadow: inset 0 5px 0 grey, 0 -5px 0 grey
  }
  #example-2 {
      border-top:10px solid grey;
      position:relative;
  }
  #example-2:before {
      content:"";
      position:absolute;
      width:100%;
      height:0;
      border-top:1px white dotted;
      top:-5px;
      left:0;
  }
```

Comment: @kisabelle Updated my answer, plus a JSFiddle

Comment: the link just goes to jsfiddle.net

Comment: Note that `box-shadow` isn’t supported in IE before version 9, and `::before` isn’t supported before version 8. (Of course, if you won’t use an extra HTML element or an image, those are your only options.)

Comment: Just for poops and giggles added another third option using `:before` *and* `:after` elements, giving you 5 borders to play with.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, You're right, but it's the kind of feature that would degrade gracefully, and heck, these kinds of things are just *fun* to tinker with.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite thanks very much for the notes on version support. I support IE8 and up so I will probably go with :before if I can!

Comment: @Dre that is a good point. Since this is only decorative it's not the end of the world if the user on IE8 doesn't see the border. (It's also part of the reason I didn't want to use an extra HTML element)

Answer (score 2):

you can use [box-shadow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp) from css with inset and :after or before like this

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/uXpaX/1/

```
body{
    background:#aaa;
}

figure{
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    margin:20px auto;
    background: rgb(140, 179, 140);
    padding:20px;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 0 -10px 0 black,inset 0 10px 0 black;
}
figure:after{
    position:absolute;
    top:-2px;
    left:0;
    height:1px;
    width:100%;
    content:'';
    border-top:4px dashed white;
}
```

[image]

Or you can just use box-shadow and border

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/uXpaX/

```
body{
    background:#aaa;
}

figure{
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    margin:20px auto;
    background: rgb(140, 179, 140);
    padding:20px;
    border-top: 2px dashed white;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 0 -10px 0 black,inset 0 10px 0 black;
}
```

html

```
<figure>
    <figcaption>Coustomer Care</figcaption>
    <menu type=list>
        <li>Billing</li>
        <li>Shipping & Tracking</li>
        <li>Returns & Exchanges</li>
        <li>Products & Sizing</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </menu>
</figure>
```

[image]

or use an other box-shadow trick like this

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/uXpaX/2/

[image]

```
body{
    background:#aaa;
}

figure{
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    margin:20px auto;
    background: black;
    padding:20px;
    border-top: 2px dashed white;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 0 -10px 0 black,inset 0 10px 0 black,inset 0 100em rgb(140, 179, 140);
}
```

Comment: this is great! thankyou. I've accepted the other answer because of the pseudo-element method which allows backward compatibility for IE8 and up.